PHP isset COOKIE statement not detecting cookies
I have this php code to check for a specific cookie,
if(isset($_COOKIE['user']) && $_COOKIE['user'] == 'test12345'){

 // logic
} 
else {
 // more logic
}

If I manually set the cookie value 'user' to 'test12345' it shows up in the browser devtools and burpsuite when I check the request, but it doesn't trigger the if statement, only ever does the else statement. For more context, site is HTTP, and this is a post request and I'm using firefox. Is the syntax in burpsuite correct? or is something else wrong?  Any ideas?


Have you tried setting the cookie in PHP and seeing what behavior is on subsequent load? setcookie('user', 'test12345');

What does var_dump($_COOKIE) yield?

First, I would suggest you wrap the second condition around its own parenthesis, to exclude weird conditions:
if(isset($_COOKIE['user']) && ($_COOKIE['user'] == 'test12345')){

Next, try displaying all contents from $_COOKIE:
print_r($_COOKIE);

It should return, at least, this:
Array
(
    [user] => test12345
)

Then, check if user exists in there, and if it contains the intended value (no weird encodings, spaces...). If it's not there, the data is being lost somewhere above in the script.

And, just wondering... how are you setting the cookie? Keep in mind that, if you're setting it via PHP's setcookie(), since cookies are part of the HTTP header, setcookie() must be called before any output is sent to the browser: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php.
